# restored GUI wallet from 25 seeds, balance=0

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I am using Ledger S. I had not opened it about 6 months and now when I did open it, it told me that some GUI wallet files are missing from the PC or something like that. I then restored my Monero GUI wallet from 25 seeds. Wallet and daemon are synchronised now, it took about 4 hours. But the balance is zero. I had more than 9 XMR in my wallet and now I don't see it anymore. How did this happen? Is it possible to get back my XMR?
The restore hight was 2064000.

At first I tried to restore the wallet from device: "Error writing wallet from hardware device. Check application logs" - what does this mean?

Comment: Do you see the transaction(s) depositing those 9 monero in the history ? If yes, you likely sent those monero or someone got your keys. If no, then the wallet has not scanned the chain and you need to rescan. The restore height you give seems valid though.

Comment: I had a similar issue, hoping to add some Monero purchased at Coinomi, to my GUI desktop wallet. After the consolidation procedure (2 steps) my 3.26 XMR went to zero. I attempted restoring three times one with a restore height a month before I added my XMR to GUI, one with restore height last November and finally with a zero restore height. Still at 0.000. If someone has experienced this issue with Monero Wallet GUI and can answer this/these questions, that would be excellent.